# Stop Reloading a UITableView Inside a Loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code where I am calling `self.tableView reloadData` inside the loop which is a bad idea. If I put it outside the loop then it would not work as expected since it will be called before updating the `noOfGroceryItems` field.

How can I improve it?

```
-(void) populateShoppingLists {

    [_groceriesService getAllShoppingLists:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
        }

        for(CKRecord *record in results) {

            ShoppingList *shoppingList = [[ShoppingList alloc] initWithRecord:record];

            // get the number of grocery items in the shopping list
            [_groceriesService getItemsByShoppingList:shoppingList result:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

                shoppingList.noOfGroceryItems = results.count;
                [_shoppingLists addObject:shoppingList];

                // THIS IS BAD IDEA
                **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    _shoppingLists = [_shoppingLists sort:@"title" ascending:YES];
                    [self.tableView reloadData];

                });**

            }];

        }

    }];
}
```

**Implementation for getItemsShoppingList method:**

```
-(void) getItemsByShoppingList:(ShoppingList *)shoppingList result:(GetItemsByShoppingList) getItemsByShoppingList
{
    CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"GroceryItems" predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ShoppingList == %@",shoppingList.record]];

    [_privateDB performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        getItemsByShoppingList(results,error);

    }];
}
```

Comment: Why not just call reloadData after processing? Would be kinder to the UI thread

Comment: All calls are asynchronous.

Comment: Do you own the `_groceriesService ` API, or is it something that you may not touch?

Comment: WOW! Down votes!! Unbelievable!

Comment: a bad question and an arrogant attitude — what else did u expect?

Comment: I guess if I want a better solution and want be a better programmer than that is considered an arrogant attitude. Sad world we live in..

Comment: While I had disagreements with Lyndsay before, it is apparent from here profile, that she is a very good programmer — at least better than you by some magnitude. But true: sad world where noobs don't understand that they are noobs.

Comment: I thank Lyndsey for her help! That is the solution I implemented using her help! But I will definitely look for other solutions so I can become a better developer. Thanks!

Comment: you won't become a better developer by being rude. you need the more experienced developers. they don't need you.

Comment: I am not rude! You are just too sensitive :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a conditional to reload the table if and only if the last shopping list has been fetched, ex:

```
[_groceriesService getAllShoppingLists:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }

    // Variable to count the number
    // of records processed
    __block int recordsProcessed = 0;

    for(CKRecord *record in results) {

        ShoppingList *shoppingList = [[ShoppingList alloc] initWithRecord:record];

        // (I've changed this second results variable from results
        // to results2 in order to distinguish between the two
        // "results" variables.)

        // get the number of grocery items in the shopping list
        [_groceriesService getItemsByShoppingList:shoppingList 
                           result:^(NSArray *results2, NSError *error) {

            shoppingList.noOfGroceryItems = results2.count;
            [_shoppingLists addObject:shoppingList];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                _shoppingLists = [_shoppingLists sort:@"title" ascending:YES];

                // Increment recordsProcessed to indicate another
                // record has been processed
                recordsProcessed ++; 

                // If all the records have been processed,
                // reload the table (using the outer block's
                // results variable, not the inner block's result2
                // variable).
                if (recordsProcessed == results.count) {
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                }

            });
        }];
    }
}];
```

**Update:** And a second solution. Assuming that `_shoppingLists` starts out empty, you can simply compare `results` with the number of elements put into `_shoppingLists`, ex:

```
[_groceriesService getAllShoppingLists:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }

    for(CKRecord *record in results) {

        ShoppingList *shoppingList = [[ShoppingList alloc] initWithRecord:record];

        // (I've changed this second results variable from results
        // to results2 in order to distinguish between the two
        // "results" variables.)

        // get the number of grocery items in the shopping list
        [_groceriesService getItemsByShoppingList:shoppingList 
                           result:^(NSArray *results2, NSError *error) {

            shoppingList.noOfGroceryItems = results2.count;
            [_shoppingLists addObject:shoppingList];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                _shoppingLists = [_shoppingLists sort:@"title" ascending:YES];

                // If the number of shopping lists stored
                // equals the number of records processed,
                // reload the table (using the outer block's
                // results variable, not the inner block's result2
                // variable).
                if (_shoppingLists.count == results.count) {
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                }

            });
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Not going to work if the results.count is returned as 0 which is a real world scenario.

Comment: @johndoe oh, no... Just realized there are two results variables... I'm talking about the first. Answering from my phone though, so I'll specify once I get to a proper computer in a few minutes

Comment: @johndoe I've made the update to distinguish between `results` and `results2`, and yes, it should work, since if `results` == 0, the loop won't execute in the first place.

Comment: @johndoe nothing prevents you from checking that the results array contains 0 objects and updating your UI to reflect such case.

Comment: Why? That is a perfectly common and well-established practice. As long as you only have one method for updating your UI, you should be fine with calling it from multiple places.

Comment: Also, you initial code doesn't even treat that problem. If `results` is empty, the for loop isn't entered.

Comment: @johndoe Seriously though... I took my time to answer your question and have provided a working answer and you're telling me "It is just not a very good solution."? What's your reasoning behind that?

Comment: I will accept your answer since currently it is a working solution. I do believe there is a better solution. The whole idea of incrementing and checking records processed sounds dirty coding. The best solution would be if I would be able to get count by joining records.

Comment: @johndoe Actually, that's fair enough... I'll provide one more solution that does something like you're describing...

Comment: @johndoe Updated to add a solution "more to your liking"... though I still find it very rude that you decided my original solution was "not very good" when you're the one coming on the forum to ask a question you don't know the solution to... If you don't like a certain working solution, I feel as if it's your responsibility to code one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a `dispatch_async` **after** the for loop, you're guaranteed that the block will be dispatched on the main queue, after the loops completes (and your data is updated).

Why not just dispatch the `reloadData` call **once** after all your model are processed and updated?

Comment: That would be true if `getItemsByShoppingList` were synchronous. I doubt that it is synchronous, though.

Comment: Inside the loop I am making async calls to get the no of items. That is why the dispatch if after the loop will be invoked immediately.

Comment: I am using CloudKit for my backend. Is there anyway I can do synchronous calls using CloudKit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fast enumerating the results array, you could enumerate with a block, that gives you the index of the current object. if the index is `[results count] - 1`, trigger the reload.

Of course you should not name two arrays results if the inner one does hide the outer, especially if you intend to call other peoples code *«not a very good solution.»*